# Apply custom discount to the grand total depending on the grand total amount in Mangento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, discount, coupon

I want to apply a 10 percent discount for the whole total. However, if the discount amount is greater than $100, I would like to only apply $100 fixed price instead of 10%. For example if 2 items total to $200, the 10% will apply and if the total is $2,000, only apply $100 discount.

I am using an observer

```
sales_quote_collect_totals_after
```

and that seems to work but don't know the code logic.

```
        $discountAmount= ((float) $oCoupon->getDiscountAmount()/100) *$total;
        if ($discountAmount>100) {
            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){

                $item->setDiscountAmount(100);
                $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(100);
                $item->setCustomPrice($total - 100);

                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $item->save();
            }

        }
```

Every time I run this code, the item changes its price and the whole total as well. I don't want the items to change their price, only the grand total and the discount amount. Does any one know how I would go about doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this can help you check that out.as keep the code that much you needed.

```
 $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
       $quoteid=$quote->getId();
                  $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
    //check condition here if need to apply Discount      $discountAmount= ((float) $oCoupon->getDiscountAmount()/100) *$total;



 if($quoteid) {
           if($discountAmount>100) {
       $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
       $quote->setSubtotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

       $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

       $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


       $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
       foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

                $address->setSubtotal(0);
                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $address->collectTotals();

                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );

                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

       $quote ->save(); 

          $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->save(); 


        if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {

         $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Amount Waived');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         }else {
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription('Amount Waived');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         }
         $address->save();
        }//end: if
       } //end: foreach
       //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();

      foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                     //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                     $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
                     $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
                     $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                     $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();

                   }


                }

        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately I have used this code and it's not exactly what I need.I forgot to mention that there is going to be a cart price rule of 10% and when the coupon is applied, no matter what I do, it always applies 10% and I cannot change it to $100. Just wanted to mention that the coupon is used not just for one customer so this rule will apply differently.

Comment: with few modifications, I was able to get it to work. I am now trying to figure out how to make give discount for the whole order $100 but what it does is adding $100 for each item and if I have 2 items in the cart that total to more than $2000, I get $200 off instead of $100. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I found this useful, thanks, but I need a way to remove the discount when a condition is true, so I don't know how to re-calculate again using the full price without discounts.